# Chrome extension storage to sync a boolean between two windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have two windows open, each being controlled by Selenium and a chrome extension is added to each window at startup. the extension has the same ID on both windows.

On each window it's respective chrome extension is looking for a button to click as fast as possible, **but the button cannot be clicked on both windows**.

It's essentially a race condition between two chrome windows with their own instances of the same extension. and the extensions needs to sync through chrome.storage to make sure the button is not clicked on both windows.

**How can I store a condition in chrome.storage in a way that the extension in each window will be able to get and set a mutually accessible boolean in storage to make sure that the other extension in the other window has not clicked the button first?**

currently I've tried turning off the extension via Selenium on window2 if the button is clicked on window1. the problem is that there is still a few milliseconds where window2 might execute a click before it's stopped by selenium, ideally the chrome extension will check via chrome.storage and prevent itself if `buttonClickedByOtherWindow == true`.